# Why doesn't react-sticky work in this simple example?

Tags: reactjs, react-sticky

I'm trying to make some header information remain at the top of the screen using [react-sticky](https://github.com/captivationsoftware/react-sticky).

However, the header just scrolls of the screen as in a normal page. Tested using Chrome and Edge on Windows 10. Same thing in both browsers. Served using webpack-dev-server.

I created the app using create-react-app. The relevant code is

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StickyContainer, Sticky } from "react-sticky";
import Lorem from "react-lorem-component";

const App = () =>
    <StickyContainer>
      <Sticky>
        { () => <h1 style={{ backgroundColor: "#00ff00" }}>Sticky Demo!"</h1> }
      </Sticky>

      <Lorem count={50} />
    </StickyContainer>;

export default App;
```

I'm using the latest libraries. Here's the package.json

```
{
  "name": "sticky-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-lorem-component": "^0.12.1",
    "react-sticky": "^6.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "1.0.7"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

Something staring me in the face that I'm missing, surely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass the `style` prop to your sticky element, for example like so:

```js
<Sticky>
  {({ style }) => <h1 style={{ ...style, backgroundColor: '#00ff00' }}>Sticky Demo!"</h1>}
</Sticky>
```

This is using the spread operator from the [`stage-0` preset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-stage-0), which you'd need to install and add to your `.babelrc`. There's other ways to combine two objects though, this is just a preference.

Comment: Thanks. I've been trying to find out why this is causing a problem with Material-UI and ended up stripping it back so far that even the div didn't work. I knew about style, but had lost sight of it in the frustration. Thank you.